# Combining (m,m,n) arrays of the lists into an (m,m,n) array

Tags: arrays, r

What would be fast and dirty way to combine arrays of m,m,n dimensions, stored in series of lists into one array of m,m,n dimensions?

**Example:**

Here are three lists with arrays of m,m,n dimensions:

```
list1 <- array (1, dim = c(5, 5, 3)) 
list2 <- array (2, dim = c(5, 5, 3)) 
list3 <- array (3, dim = c(5, 5, 3))
```

Combined lists of m,m,n dimensions:

```
lists <- list(list1 = list1, list2 = list2, list3 = list3)
```

I want to perform a function on the "lists" object that gives me one array of m,m,n dimensions (***e.g. "want.to.get" output***)

```
want.to.get <- array (rep (1:3, each = 5*5*3), dim = c(5,5,9))
```

Comment: What do you mean by combining? by which dimension?

Comment: @OganM, I just wanted to concatenate arrays (of the same dimensions) over the lists of a list...(e.g. lists = list_1(arrays_1), list_2(arrays_2),...,list_n(array_n) into arrays = arrays_1, arrays_2,..., arrays_n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(abind)
abind(lists, new.names = list(NULL, NULL, 1:9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could `unlist` and specify the `dim` in `array`

```
dim1 <- dim(lists[[1]])*c(1,1,length(lists))
ar1 <- array(unlist(lists, use.names=FALSE), dim=dim1)
all.equal(ar1, want.to.get)
#[1] TRUE
```